# Post order to oanda API using requests in python

Tags: python, python-requests

I am getting this error:   "Unsupported ContentType: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

This is what I am sending:

```
body = {
        'order':
            {
                'units':f'{units}',
                'instrument':f'{self.strategy.instrument.pair}',
                'type':f'{self.strategy.ord_type}',
                'postionFill':'DEFAULT',
                'stopLossOnFill':
                {
                    'timeInForce': 'GTC',
                    'price': f'{self.strategy.instrument.last_close * stop_loss}'
                },
                'takeProfitOnFill':
                {
                'price':f'{self.strategy.instrument.last_close * take_profit}'
                }
            }
        }



  head = {
  'Authorization': self.user.auth_tok['Authorization']
  }

##https://api-fxpractice.oanda.com/v3/accounts/ <account> /orders##

self.url = f'{self.user.url}/accounts/{self.user.account_id}/orders'

response = requests.post(self.url, headers = head, data = body)
```

I am able to get the candle data and account info and do other stuff.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the correct content-type to the header. E.g:

```
    head = {
  'Authorization': self.user.auth_tok['Authorization'],
  'content-type': 'application/json',
  'Accept':'application/json' # possibly you may need this for 415 errors
  }
```

All you should be able to pass the JSON in directly:

```
response = requests.post(self.url, headers = head, json=body)
```

Comment: I have tried various versions of these and keep getting different errors. if I use dumps then I get a unreported content type. If I put the content type in there then I get a header is invalid for authorization error.

Comment: Perhaps try calling the API from Postman and then it should be easier to determine what parameters are missing or incorrect. If yo get unsupported content, then you may need to add Accept to header. I've eddited it above. If you get invalid authorization then it suggests that self.user.auth_tok['Authorization'] is incorrect or it needs to be encoded/decoded.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on that idea! I should be able to work it out.

Comment: I ended up using http.client in python and still wasn't successful until I put a capital on Bearer in the Auth!!!!! Such a minor Detail... hahaha

Answer (score 0):

Add `'Content-type': 'application/json'`  to your headers and wrap your data with json.dumps() function.

head may look like

```
head = {
  'Content-type': 'application/json',
  'Authorization': self.user.auth_tok['Authorization']
  }
```

and post may look like

```
response = requests.post(self.url, headers = head, data = json.dumps(body))
```

Don't forget to `import json` at the top of your script.